# CollectionView Cell changes on tab navigating

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been creating a webservice which collects mysql data and this is being sent to the App using AFNetworking into the NSMutableArray imagesArray

I'm using DTCoreText to extract the image urls and then place them into the collectionView Cell.

The problem is when i navigate to another ViewController and go back a strange thing happens. The Cell which contain no image gains the image which is in another cell.

Image illustration:

As you can see i've made an if and else statement, so an image should not be able to have an image and the camera image?

The app opens:

[image]

After i've navigated to another viewController and back to this:

[image]

My code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     collectionCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIColor * borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226/255.0f green:221/255.0f blue:219/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;



    cell.self.theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200-50, screenWidth/2-8, 50)];
    cell.self.theView .backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.self.theView];

    cell.self.theTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, screenWidth/2-8-5, 30)];
    cell.self.theTitle.textColor = tintColor;
    [cell.self.theTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12]];
    cell.self.theTitle.text = [[imagesArray valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.self.theView  addSubview: cell.self.theTitle];

    UIView *bottomLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.self.theView.frame.size.height-2, cell.self.theView.frame.size.width, 2)];
    bottomLineView.backgroundColor = borderColor;
    [cell.self.theView addSubview:bottomLineView];

    NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:[[imagesArray valueForKey:@"content"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [[[imagesArray valueForKey:@"content"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] length])];


    NSArray *imageExtensions = @[@"png", @"jpg", @"gif", @"jpeg"];

    Images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Iterate & match the URL objects from your checking results
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *result in matches) {
        NSURL *url = [result URL];
        NSString *extension = [url pathExtension];
            if ([imageExtensions containsObject:extension]) {
                NSLog(@"Image URL: %@", url);
                [Images addObject:url];
            } else {

            }
    }


    if(Images.count > 0)
        {

        cell.self.theImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth/2-8, 150)];
        UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Images objectAtIndex:0] ]]]];
        [cell.self.theImage setImage:myImage];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.self.theImage];


        } else {
            cell.self.theImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth/2-8-5)/2-25, 80-25, 50, 50)];
            UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera"];
            [cell.self.theImage setImage:myImage];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.self.theImage];
        }






    return cell;
}
```

ViewWillAppear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [imagesArray removeAllObjects];
    [self getImages];
}
```

Comment: are you using any code in viewWillAppear?Can you show some more code so i can understand.?

Comment: I've added into the question

Comment: What happens in getImages? Why do you reload all images in viewWillAppear?

Comment: BTW, sell.theTitle should be equivalent to self.self.theTitle. And please let you class names begin with upper case letters.

Comment: Well i want to update the images everytime the viewload i guess? incase of a new post? what would be ideal?

Comment: in top of getImages i     [imagesArray removeAllObjects];
    [Images removeAllObjects];

Answer (score 0):

For a start, read some tutorial about the re-using mechanism of cells. 
When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` for the first times you will get newly allocated cells (assuming the cells come from a storyboard or you registered the cell class and assigned it to the identifier `"cell"`).

When it is a newly created cell object then you may be right with creating all the subviews and add them as subviews. 
But when the user scrolls further down or up then `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` will return an existing cell that has got its subviews already. In that case you just need to refresh their content. 
But you creat new lables and image views etc and just place them on the same location so that they just hide (in the best case) the original UI elements that have been there before. 
In the best case this is just some sort of memory leak.

Frankly, I don't know by heard if cellForItemAtIndexPath is called again for each visible cell when the view comes into sight after the user navigated back to it using the tab bar. I don't think so but would not be surprised.

Strange effects come up until you really understand this mechanism and design your code accordingly. That is why I suggest fixing these issues first and design your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` so that it complies with the re-using mechanism. That will solve most of the problems like yours. 
If it does not fix it then get back to us with a new question and with the refactured cocde.